How to use gcc compilation flags to make the .data section of the program execute code
I use -z execstack flag, But it can't work. Only the stack has execution permissions, not the .data segment.
Mapped address spaces:

          Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset  Perms  objfile
      0x555555554000     0x555555555000     0x1000        0x0  r--p   /home/hello/pwn_basic/Labs/Lab 3/Lab 3/ret2sc
      0x555555555000     0x555555556000     0x1000     0x1000  r-xp   /home/hello/pwn_basic/Labs/Lab 3/Lab 3/ret2sc
      0x555555556000     0x555555557000     0x1000     0x2000  r--p   /home/hello/pwn_basic/Labs/Lab 3/Lab 3/ret2sc
      0x555555557000     0x555555558000     0x1000     0x2000  r--p   /home/hello/pwn_basic/Labs/Lab 3/Lab 3/ret2sc
      0x555555558000     0x555555559000     0x1000     0x3000  rw-p   /home/hello/pwn_basic/Labs/Lab 3/Lab 3/ret2sc
      0x7ffff7d83000     0x7ffff7d86000     0x3000        0x0  rw-p   
      0x7ffff7d86000     0x7ffff7dae000    0x28000        0x0  r--p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      0x7ffff7dae000     0x7ffff7f43000   0x195000    0x28000  r-xp   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      0x7ffff7f43000     0x7ffff7f9b000    0x58000   0x1bd000  r--p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      0x7ffff7f9b000     0x7ffff7f9c000     0x1000   0x215000  ---p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      0x7ffff7f9c000     0x7ffff7fa0000     0x4000   0x215000  r--p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      0x7ffff7fa0000     0x7ffff7fa2000     0x2000   0x219000  rw-p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      0x7ffff7fa2000     0x7ffff7faf000     0xd000        0x0  rw-p   
      0x7ffff7fbb000     0x7ffff7fbd000     0x2000        0x0  rw-p   
      0x7ffff7fbd000     0x7ffff7fc1000     0x4000        0x0  r--p   [vvar]
      0x7ffff7fc1000     0x7ffff7fc3000     0x2000        0x0  r-xp   [vdso]
      0x7ffff7fc3000     0x7ffff7fc5000     0x2000        0x0  r--p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      0x7ffff7fc5000     0x7ffff7fef000    0x2a000     0x2000  r-xp   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      0x7ffff7fef000     0x7ffff7ffa000     0xb000    0x2c000  r--p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      0x7ffff7ffb000     0x7ffff7ffd000     0x2000    0x37000  r--p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      0x7ffff7ffd000     0x7ffff7fff000     0x2000    0x39000  rw-p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      0x7ffffffdd000     0x7ffffffff000    0x22000        0x0  rwxp   [stack]

how to use the ld linker and change the execution permissions of the data segment? This is an exercise. I can't use mmap because I was asked not to change source file.

This is an exercise of what?  The data segment is INTENTIONALLY read/write without execute.  Everyone now knows that R/W/X segments are extremely poor practice and are thus not allowed.

pwn lab, I need a buggy program
